# Views using an incorrect column name in my join statement

Tags: views, 8

I have an Entity with an entity reference to another Entity. The field is defined as:

```
$fields['sample'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Analysis Samples'))
  ->setCardinality(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
  ->setSettings(array(
    'target_type' => 'sample',
  ))
  ->setDescription(t('Samples for Analysis.'))
  ->setDefaultValue('')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setRequired(FALSE);
```

In the database, this created a new table that looks like this:

```
mysql> describe fermentor__sample;
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bundle           | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted          | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| langcode         | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sample_target_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

When I make a view, and try to set a relationship between Fermentor and Sample, it tries to join on a column called fermentor__sample.sample instead of fermentor__sample.sample_target_id:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fermentor__sample.sample' in 'on clause': SELECT fermentor.id AS id, sample_fermentor__sample.id AS sample_fermentor__sample_id FROM {fermentor} fermentor LEFT JOIN {fermentor__sample} fermentor__sample ON fermentor.id = fermentor__sample.entity_id AND fermentor__sample.deleted = :views_join_condition_0 INNER JOIN {sample} sample_fermentor__sample ON fermentor__sample.sample = sample_fermentor__sample.id; Array ( [:views_join_condition_0] => 0 )

Is this a bug in Views, or do I need to specify the correct join column in my Entity's ViewsData Object?

Comment: Sounds like https://www.drupal.org/node/2846614

Comment: This bug has been fixed in drupal 8.5